# "c++" argument not accepting by SonarQube Web API

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have a use case where I upload a C++ quality profile in SonarQube 7.X (LTS version) and then:

1. Search for it.
2. Set it as default quality profile.

I have no problem in uploading the quality profile to SonarQube portal.
However, when I try to search for it using the /search API and set it as default using /set_default API, the parameter 'language' does not accept 'c++' value.
It gives response to use 'c++' as language and that I only provided value 'c' as request.

It seems it is unable to process '+' sign in 'c++'.
[image]
Is there any alternative for this approach.
(Also, when I do not provide any language while searching for profiles, a 'c++' language profile that I uploaded is received as response to verify that my profile is uploading OK)

Answer (score 0):

`+` is a special character in URL meaning a space. If you need to have a literal +, you would probably need to urlencode it as `c%2B%2B`

Comment: Also, I'm implementing the CURL call in a .bat file. Now, in a .bat file %2 is understood as an argument. I've tried escaping the first % sign but then the second % sign for second %2B does not get escaped at all. Is there any solution to pass this as a string in .bat file?

Comment: In that case write in your .bat file `c%%2B%%2B`.